# SoftKeyboard is not appering in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to show soft keyboard , when my edittext get focus.
I have wrote following code to do that.
But still keyboard is not appearing though my edittext is getting focus.

```
   private void VerifyCodeEditText_FocusChange(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.HasFocus)
        {
            var inputManager = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            inputManager.ShowSoftInput(VerifyCodeEditText, ShowFlags.Implicit);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my utility method for showing the soft input.

```
private void ShowSoftKeyboard(View input, bool selectText)
{
    if (selectText) ((EditText)input).SelectAll();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100); // For some reason, a short delay is required here.
        RunOnUiThread(() => ((InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService)).ShowSoftInput(input, ShowFlags.Implicit));
    });
}
```

It's the same call as yours inside, but I ensure it runs on the UI thread and I found that I needed a brief delay for it to work.

This should get you working. Maybe someone can even improve mine :)

Comment: that was the trick to solving my problem, thank you very much